# image overlapping with text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am new to coding. My image is overlapping with the text in the about us section.
in the tutorial I'm watching the text is next to the image. It does not overlap with it. Any help?

```css
* {
  font-family: "Poppins ", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  padding: 100px;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row .co150 {
  position: relative;
  width: 48%;
}
```

```html
<section class="about " id="about ">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="co150 ">
      <h2 class="titleText "><span>A</span>bout Us</h2>
      <p>udgugqguugdugwugugugduqugdg qwuuuuuuuuuuu uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa zzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzz mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj hhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.
        <br><br>lorem ipsum dolores umbridge x her husband blalalalallllllllllllllllllllllll .
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="co150 ">
      <div class="imgBx ">
        <img src="img1.jpg ">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: we know nothing about the tutorial you are following and what result is expected here. what we can see is that you do not (re)set any rules to <img>  and that your impossible text doesn't wrap. ... use fake text like lorem ipsum for possible text

Comment: you dont need `position: relative;` if you not to intend to have a child with `position: absolute;` last but not least, your code is working fine as intended. Just with the text you using without space or declare line-break-point it will cause an overflow

Comment: Seems like you are using bootstrap. Try to divide row in to two columns.
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md=3">
your image goes here
</div>

<div class="col-md=9">
your textgoes here
</div>

</div>

Comment: @BonieZat he claerly declaring CSS. besides the 2 column work as intended. Its just his impossible text without any breakpoints/wrap that causes the overflow.

Comment: What does the image look like?

Comment: can u please look at the tutorial and help out?
link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ac5nmWOkBEY

timestamp: 13:05-14:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `inline-block` your objects will be side-by-side and giving both objects `width of 100%` so they will take their respective parent's width. Finally, in the case of text, I gave `overflow-wrap: break-word` so the text will not collapse with the image

```css
* {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  padding: 100px;
}

.row .co150 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 48%;
}
 .co150 p {
   width: 100%;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
   
   
 }
.imgBx {
  width: 100%;
}
.imgBx img {
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section class="about" id="about">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="co150">
      <h2 class="titleText"><span>A</span>bout Us</h2>
      <p>udgugqguugdugwugugugduqugdgqwuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.
        <br><br>lorem ipsum dolores umbridge x her husband blalalalallllllllllllllllllllllll .
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="co150">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/425/536/354.jpg?hmac=wBNHXWWIrsjZJiC-motCXU36RWkqnUAAPfVJulwHGHM">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Working **FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vo5zjsqa/)